# How do I add Docker Container permissions?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, file-permissions, nfs, nas

My docker containers are getting a permission denied error when starting, due to being unable to write to an NFS share.

ERROR: for docker_container Cannot start service docker_container: error while creating mount source path `'/mnt/media/books': mkdir /mnt/media/books: permission denied`
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

My docker-compose file is version 3.9 :

```
docker_container:
    container_name: docker_container
    image: linuxserver/docker_container
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    user: "1004:1000"
    environment:
      #- PUID=1004
      #- PGID=1000
      - TZ=America/Chicago
    volumes:
      - "/home/docker/readarr/config:/config"
      - "/mnt/media/books/:/mnt/media/books"
      - "/mnt/media/torrents/:/mnt/media/torrents"
```

My fstab to nfs share:

`10.0.20.22:/mnt/vol1/media      /mnt/media      nfs4    rw,_netdev,soft,timeo=30        0 0`

I added the PUID 1004 and GUID 1000. On TrueNAS Scale, where the media folder is hosted, I created a local group, gid 1000, and added the ACL to allow rw on the media share. On the host, I can access the folder and write to it. However, the docker container cannot modify any permissions. The server is Ubuntu 22.04.

If I use `docker exec -it --user 1004 bash`, I can modify and delete as I please, though. Root does also get access denied.

I've restarted the docker service and rebooted the server as well. I have another server running TrueNAS and I compared the docker-compose and ACLs and everything seems to be the same.